# php one page 2 result

Tags: php, session

this is my code after success enter login and password

```
<?php session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['nik'])){ die("Anda belum login");} 
if($_SESSION['level']!="admin"){ 
echo "<h3>Welcome ".$_SESSION['nik']."</h3>";
echo "panel user";
} 
if($_SESSION['level']="admin"){
echo "panel admin";
}
?>
<a href=log.php?op=selesai>Log Out</a>
```

the out put that i want is :
if login = admin then display "hello admin"
if login = user then display "hello user"
if not login then say "you must login"

any suggestion how to fix that ?

Comment: Change if($_SESSION['level']="admin") to if($_SESSION['level']=="admin") You are supposed to compare and not assign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please find below code as per your requirements.

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['nik'])){ 
      echo "You must login.";
      exit;
  } 
  if($_SESSION['level']!="admin"){ 
              echo "<h3>Welcome ".$_SESSION['level']."</h3>";
              echo '<a href=log.php?op=selesai>Log Out</a>';
              exit;
  }
  else {
       echo "<h3>Welcome ".$_SESSION['level']."</h3>";
       echo '<a href=log.php?op=selesai>Log Out</a>';
  }
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i choose and use @Ghanshyam answer,
thank you to all member at stackoverflow.
this is very helpfull site

Comment: that does not meaning other answer is wrong. but i am a beginner perhaps, this answer is more suitable for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Use following statement to set session for username while login-

    session_start();
    //following statement will create a session store user name.You can use this variable to display particular output.
    $_SESSION["uname"] = $_GET['un'];
    //in above statement 'un' is text box from which we are accepting username.
```

After set session variable for user name you can use it on another page-

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["uname"]) )
{
   if($_SESSION["uname"] == 'admin')
   {
     echo 'hello admin';
   }
   else($_SESSION["uname"] == 'uname')
   {
      echo 'hello user';
   }
}
else
{
echo "you must login"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your operator selection.

```
if($_SESSION['level']="admin"){
echo "panel admin";
}
```

should be

```
if($_SESSION['level'] == "admin"){
echo "panel admin";
}
```

`=` is an assignment operator. And you need to use `==` or `===`